# Unsure of how ISEB Intermediate answer is correct

Tags: test-management, iseb

So I'm sitting my ISEB Intermediate on Thursday and, going through some mock papers now, I've been presented with a problem statement which (no matter how many times I read it), I just can't understand how they arrive to a different conclusion. So bear with me on this one...

---

### **Problem statement:**

The project manager is concerned that poor quality releases are being delivered by development and this is affecting the time necessary to complete testing and will ultimately effect the project deadline. You have offered to help identify entry criteria for system testing.

---

### **Question:**

Which of the following entry criteria would you recommend for system testing in the circumstances described above?

a. 100% of the code coverage is achieved

b. Development have tested the release in their environment and it works with no major issues

c. All high risk requirements have been tested

d. Relevant boundary and partition tests have passed

e. System testing environment has been tested and passed

f. Static analysis has been performed and there are no outstanding issues

---

A. a, b and c.

B. b, d and e.

C. b, d and f.

D. a, c and e.

---

So first time round, I incorrectly answered A. Which is fine... I get why it isn't A. (it's unreasonable for QA to expect Dev are able to achieve 100% code coverage at unit integration level)

I had another go and figured it *could* be D... but that's wrong also.

** **Spoiler alert!!!** ** The correct answer is B. So apparently it makes more sense to suggest that relevant boundary and partition test have passed unit integration rather than ensuring that all high risk requirements have been tested.

Does that sound right? Or am I completely missing the point of reasonable entry criteria for system testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that (a) is wrong, which eliminates A and D. Not sure why you thought it might be D: it shares wrong (a).

So you need to decide between B and C answers. Both suggest (b) and (d). Difference is: Which one to add along (b) and (d)?  (e) or (f)?

So question is: why (e) and not (f):

- e. System testing environment has been tested and passed
- f. Static analysis has been performed and there are no outstanding issues

(e) looks more promising for me - and I never studied for ISEB, even entry level :-). Static analysis seems similar to 100% coverage; not a real executable test.

Comment: To expand on this: Static program analysis is the analysis of computer software that is performed without actually executing programs.